# SQL Column will not allow entry after being altered

Tags: sql, sql-server, truncate, alter-table

I have a SQL table that has a column "Stamp" the was originally setup as nchar(10). The data that was entered in this field was only 9 characters long (ie. XX111.jpg)  However, I have changed the format of the data being entered. It is now XX-XXX111.jpg. I ran this alter statement to increase the column size:

```
Alter Table tblData
Alter Column Stamp nvarchar(50)
```

Afterwards I would run an update statement to update the NULL values in the database:

```
Update tblData Set Stamp = 'XX-XXX111.jpg' where Updated > '2014-08-01' and Stamp is null
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
(22 row(s) affected)
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure ChangedMECTrigger, Line 31
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I don't understand how this is not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you get a positiv feedback from your "Alter" commands? First guess would be that they don't work because of insufficient rights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently have a trigger on the table:
`ChangedMECTrigger`
You need to update the data length on this too.

You can find those in SSMS here:

[image]

Comment: where are those normally found?

Comment: I found it.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

there's a trigger tied to tblData called ChangedMECTrigger.  Something in the trigger's logic is causing the error.  You could temporarily disable the trigger prior to running your `update tblData...` statement like this:

```
disable trigger ChangedMECTrigger on tblData
Update tblData Set Stamp = 'XX-XXX111.jpg' where Updated > '2014-08-01' and Stamp is null
enable trigger ChangedMECTrigger on tblData
```

or you could look at the trigger's code to find the issue.  Chances are there's something in the trigger using nchar(10) still and needs to be updated to nvarchar(50).